# Tablet: Set Chrome as Default Web Browser on Lenovo Tab 4

Tags: chrome-for-android, tablet, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Tab 4 8".  I've tried clearing defaults, uninstalling and reinstalling .. but yet when I try to open an html file on my the SD Card of my tablet I only get the option to use the HTML Viewer.  I would like to set Chrome as available in these options or as the default for opening all HTML files.

Comment: Try setting defaults with [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.betteropenwith)

Comment: If it doesn't give you the option, it's usually because chrome can't open such a file

Comment: To "A Bochur" - Chrome can't open an html file, such as index.html?

Comment: To "beeshyams" - nice app.  Thank you.  I've set Chrome as my default browser with this app. And there is Chrome.  And it opens my index.html file on my attached usb.  So awesome and thank you!!!!